# Create a "Template" SQL in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a set of SQL queries built for SSRS.  I am building 
reports for multiple customers and my queries apply to all of them
- except I have to replace the company name in the WHERE clause.

Can SSRS create a "template" SQL query and automatically replace
the company name and apply according to the appropriate company 
name?

Comment: Why not use a single parameterised stored procedure (where the company name is a parameter provided to the report)?

Comment: Or if you want to keep it all in SSRS you can create a shared dataset with the query that takes the company name as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to achieve this is with an SSRS parameter. If you right click the parameters and add one I call mine "client" but you can use company name etc if you prefer.

[image: add]

If you only have a few options for companies you can add them in manually as "available values" but a good option if you have lots of posilbilities is to create a dataset (paramset) from new query that is simply

> SELECT
>
> distinct
>
> [Company Name]
>
> From {your table}

Then you can use the "get values from a query" option to automatically fill the parameter drop down box with all the potential options.

[image]

After that all you need to do is add

```
Where [Company Name] = (@Client) or @{whatever your parameter is called}
```

to your query. When you run the report you should get a dropdown box with all the company names in it and from there you can pick one and it should apply the filter to your data automatically. That way you can build one report and run it for as many companies as you like.